# I can't remove alarms set with old apple mail app

Tags: mail.app, ical

I set some alarms using older mail program that came with OS X 10.6. During all upgrades, the alerts were preserved, but now I want to remove them and I can't find where they are defined. They are not in reminders, not in calendar, not on mail program. I'm now running on iMac, OS X Mavericks (10.9.3)

Comment: so how do you get the reminder ? by whom ?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. Back in the days of OS X 10.6, the mail app had a note button and I could higlight a text and make it a to do item with an alarm. See this post here: [http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2500](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2500). That's what I did and now I can't find where these odl arlams are defined to remove them. I have one to send me a message once a month and I'm still receiving it every month.

Answer (score 1):

In Reminders there should be a folder titled 'Notes' where all your old Mail todo's have been moved.  To see your folders you have to click one of the buttons on the bottom right of the side-menu.  There should be a similar folder in the Notes application where all your old Mail notes have been moved.

Comment: On my Reminders here (Mavericks) there are no right side buttons, only bottom left buttons, and when the side bar is expanded, I see only Completed, Today, and then the iCloud folders.